# Multiline string is being joined when using dom4j

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

I'm using jdom4 to read xml document. When I'm getting the **valueOf** node element as string the line seperators are removed and string is retrieved as one-line.

Is there a way I can preserve the line spacing to read the output line by line for further manipulation?

Example

```
    <Text>
        CURRENT VIRAL LOAD:24707 cps/mL
        CD4/CD8 COUNT     :Not known
        CURRENT THERAPY   :Truvada (TDF, FTC); Anzavir-R (boosted
        atazanavir)
        PREVIOUS THERAPY  :2007-2008 Viramune (NVP); Lamzid (AZT,
        3TC)
                  :2008-2013 Truvada (TDF, FTC); Aluvia
        HIV-SUBTYPE       :C
    </Text>
```

Now following code:

```
    document.valueOf("..../Text")
```

produces only one string line

Comment: Please show the code you are using.

Comment: Found my solution - used Node selectSingleNode then used Node.getText() and now the String value returns the \n at the end of each line - thanks anyway :)